# Where to get the right inforamtion about place_id and EVENT_ROLE?

Tags: python, facebook, events, facebook-graph-api

I would like to know how to create an event with the graph api?

I have tried the following:

```
def createEvent(self,body):
        return requests.post('https://graph.facebook.com/official_events', data=json.dumps(body))
```

I can retrieve and display my own data. 
I can also post contributions on my own the website.

I have difficulties in determining which elements must be included in the content-body and which are variable.

additionally I wonder where I get the information about the `place-id` and `roles":{"{page_id}":"{EVENT_ROLE}"}`
I know the information about `page_id` but where do I get the information about `EVENT_ROLE`?

And what is it needed for?

Link: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/pages/official-events/getting-started
in the documentation it should look like this, but unfortunately I lack the above mentioned information

Comment: good news, i had to paste my own 'place id'  only one thing is missing, what is a 'Event_role'

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/pages/official-events/getting-started#categories---roles explains what roles are (briefly). The link behind _“You can the see the list of Roles and Categories in the Official Events API Reference Documentation”_ there does not work for me, but it says right after, _“(Note: Your application must be white listed for you to view the Reference Documentation)”_, so I suppose you should be able to see it then (if you weren’t white listed, anything you tried here should have failed pretty much from the start.)

Comment: Have you got anything on the whitelisting rqeuest for Events API docs? I don't know where to request it.